# Python-docx ignoring non-unicode Symbols like 'greater than or equal to'

Tags: python, math, ms-word, symbols, python-docx

When reading a word docx that contains tables and text with

[image: symbol]

into python with python-docx the symbols all just get dropped. The symbols were all created with the normal insert symbol steps. It says it is from the Font **Symbol**, Character code **179**, from **Symbol (decimal)**

[image: adding symbol]

Python-docx is just showing it as ''. The same for the 'plus or minus' symbol to the left of it.

When reading the text from the paragraph (not the ones in a table) I use the following code:

```
def listText():
   test = docx.Document('Problem.docx')
   testp=test.paragraphs[0] #The only paragraph in the test docx
   stringThatShouldHaveSymbol = testp.text

   print(stringThatShouldHaveSymbol)

   return stringThatShouldHaveSymbol
```

This only returns '' from a document that only contains those symbols.
If it has the symbol then 10 it will just return 10.

I also tried this xml approach, but even that returned "".

```
def get_accepted_text(p):
    """Return text of a paragraph after accepting all changes"""
    xml = p._p.xml
    if "w:del" in xml or "w:ins" in xml:
        tree = docx.Document.XML(xml)
        runs = (node.text for node in tree.getiterator(TEXT) if node.text)
        return "".join(runs)
    else:
        return p.text
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    print(p.text)
    print("---")
    print(get_accepted_text(p))
    print("=========")
```

How can I extract the data from these documents? Is there a way to programmatically convert these symbols(decimals) to Unicode(hex)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract text inserted with track-changes in python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247251/how-to-extract-text-inserted-with-track-changes-in-python-docx)

Comment: I tried the body = document._body._body section, but that just returned empty as well. Were you referring to something on that link in particular?

Comment: Yes, I was pointing to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56933021/13636314

Comment: Still just prints---

========="

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Click on the symbol drop down and select (normal text)
2. Now select your special symbol

If you now read the docx file you should get your symbol.

Not sure why the symbol font doesn't work. In Arial, 179 that is a 3 superscript.

Comment: The Symbol font doesn't assign Unicode code points to their corresponding Unicode characters.  Rather the Symbol font uses its own coded character set, perhaps to make typing special symbols more convenient, and probably dates from the late 80s to early 90s, which was when the Unicode standard was not nearly as ubiquitous as today.

Comment: I see it now in the xml view. <w:sym w:font="Symbol" w:char="F0B3"/>. It seems python-docx totally ignores these. It only likes w:t. Not sure what to do since I have hundreds of documents with these sym in tables

Comment: Looks like B3 has been replaced by F0B3 (61619).  The easiest way to replace it with 8805 is to do it in VBA.  Just loop through all the files and do a replace.

Comment: How can I run vba in my python based pipeline on linux?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know you were running on Linux.